# Python logic error?

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to flatten a list in my function but ignore that (you can also ignore the print functions I put in). 
take `x = [[1,2,3],4,5]` to be my variable. 
I call `prob7(x)` but the issue is that when `type([1,2,3])` gets checked == list, it returns false. Why is that? I explicitly check this on the interpreter command line and it returns true. But inside the function, I get a false.

Just a bug that I missed because I'm sleepy or am I misunderstanding some part of the Python language? I run version 2.6 if it matters.

```
def prob7(list): # flatten a list
    tempList = []
    if list: # meaning if there are elements in the list and it is not empty
        for i in list:
            if type(i) != list:
                print tempList,'if',i,type(i)==list
                tempList.append(i)
            else:
                print tempList,'else',i
                tempList.extend(prob7(i))

    return tempList
```

Comment: Watch out for lists nested more than `sys.getrecursionlimit()`(about 1000 lists) deep.  Since you're calling the function on the nested lists, you can hit the recursion depth limit and get a RecursionError.

Comment: dang, thank you all. much more information than i needed but still very useful overall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just not use 'list' as a variable name and use isinstance(var, list) instead of type(var) == list. 
Please find corrected sample below.

```
def prob7(mylist): # flatten a list
    tempList = []
    if mylist: # meaning if there are elements in the list and it is not empty
        for i in mylist:
            if not isinstance(i, list):
                print tempList, 'if', i, isinstance(i, list)
                tempList.append(i)
            else:
                print tempList, 'else', i
                tempList.extend(prob7(i))    
    return tempList
```

Or if you don't really required to use recursion and you don't care about values order then you can use something like this:

```
lVals = [[1,2,3],4,5, [1,[4,7]]]

def make_flat(mylist): # flatten a list    
    while any(isinstance(x, list) for x in mylist):
        for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
            if isinstance(val, list):                
                mylist.extend(mylist.pop(i))        
                break
    return mylist

make_flat(lVals)
>>> [4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Checking for an empty list before iterating over it is useless: iterating over an empty list will correctly do nothing. Special cases aren't special enough.

Comment: @Karl - sure - i just tried to fix OP sample, my code is second one.

Comment: works if i use type( ) ==, why use isinstance? i thought you only need that for subclasses

Comment: @david - sure it works but it is more pythonic to use isinstance for this purpose.

Comment: Your second example mutates the list it is iterating over. That can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Keith - what do you mean on unexpected results in this certain case?

Comment: @Artsiom The behaviour of mutating lists while iterating over them is [considered to be undefined](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/). It may work in your example, but may not, or may not with another implementation.

Comment: Yes - i know that this quite dangerous but i though that in this case - it is ok. I just can't see what can go wrong here. Sorry if i miss something

Answer (score 3):

Artisom has your answer. In addtion, type checks are not very Pythonic. [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) often is the way to go. In case your elements are numbers only, the following does the job too, without explicit type checks but behavior checks:

```
def prob7(inlist): # flatten a list
    outlist = []
    for x in inlist:
        try:
            outlist += x
        except TypeError:
            outlist.append(x)
    return outlist
```

Note that string elements in this implementation would behave like nested lists. Anyway, just wanted to illustrate what it means to expect behavior, not types.

Comment: `+=` for lists is a bit hacked. The simplest way to make strings "behave" here would be to just use `outlist = outlist + x`. Yes, with the `list` type in particular, this is not equivalent. Anyway, this only flattens one level.

Comment: Indeed, `outlist.extend(...)` might be better here. And yes, `outline + x` works as expected with strings but would also raise TypeErrors for tuple elements and it would always create new list objects. I've chosen the *one level* solution to mainly illustrate the duck typing idea. For a truly recursive flattening, `instanceof` checks would be more [explicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) in my opinion.

Comment: If you want to recursively flatten everything that can be flattened, I would duck-type by checking for whether `x` is iterable, and then special-casing when `x` has a known length of 1 (to avoid infinite recursion on strings).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using a local variable name (list) that is the same as the global `list` type. You should change your variable name. Also, when checking types like that you can use the `is` operator.

```
type(l) is list
```

But here's my version of flatten.

```
def flatten(alist):
    rv = []
    for val in alist:
        if isinstance(val, list):
            rv.extend(flatten(val))
        else:
            rv.append(val)
    return rv
```

This does not alter the original list, but returns a new list. This is consistent with most other patterns.

Comment: thank you, clearest answer here, though i will check out the isinstance stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternate approaches:

```
# Iterative, but more functional-style
def flatten(a_list):
  while any(isinstance(x, list) for x in a_list):
    a_list = sum((x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in a_list), [])
  return a_list

# Using a generator recursively, 
# then evaluating the generator to produce the list
# instead of explicitly appending each element.
def flatten_gen(a_list):
  for x in a_list:
    if isinstance(x, list):
      for y in flatten_gen(x): yield y
    else: yield x

def flatten(a_list): return list(flatten_gen(a_list))
```